# why is the overload resolution wrong here?

Tags: c++, constructor, overload-resolution

suppose we have this as our setup:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
private:
    int a;
public:
    Base(int a)
        : a(a) {
    }

    virtual void print() = 0;
};

class Child : public Base {
public:

    using Base::Base;

    void print() override {
        //some code
    }
};

class Wrapper {
private:
    void* base_ptr = nullptr;
public:
    Wrapper(void* base_ptr)
        : base_ptr(base_ptr) {
        std::cout << "void* version called\n";
    }

    Wrapper(Base* const& base_ptr)
        : base_ptr(base_ptr) {
        std::cout << "Base*const& version called\n";
    }

};
```

if we do the following:

```
Child* child_ptr = new Child(1);
Wrapper w(child_ptr);
```

output is:

```
Base*const& version called
```

which is expected and completely normal.
but if we change `Wrapper(Base *const&)` to `Wrapper(Base*&)` we call the `void*` version:

```
class Wrapper {
private:
    void* base_ptr = nullptr;
public:
    Wrapper(void* base_ptr)
        : base_ptr(base_ptr) {
        std::cout << "void* version called\n";
    }

    Wrapper(Base*& base_ptr)
        : base_ptr(base_ptr) {
        std::cout << "Base*const& version called\n";
    }

};

int main() {
    Child* child_ptr = new Child(1);
    Wrapper w(child_ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

for this version we get this output:

```
void* version called
```

but why is that? shouldn't `Base*const&` just make it also compatible with temporary objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. after sometime thinking about it, I figured it out. It's simply because there is an implicit cast happening where we try to call the constructor of second version, we change the type of `Child*` to `Base*` and because of that it's not anymore an `LValue` and becomes an `RValue`, therefore it can't bind to `Base*&` and if we were about to change its signature to `Base*&&`, it would choose this overload(which is expected because of the implicit cast happening there and making it an `RValue`).